# Как на PHP реализовать конкретный HTTP-ответ от сервера?

Tags: php, http, curl

В cURL, например, есть параметр `CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE` - последний полученный HTTP код, который активно используется во многих REST API. Как сделать этот конкретный ответ на PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как правило конкретный код устанавливает сам сервер.

Если вы хотите вручную управлять возвращаемым статусом, можно воспользоваться функцией [http_response_code](http://php.net/http-response-code) или вручную устанавливать заголовки [header](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php) `header("HTTP/1.0 " + $status)`

Статусы можно подсмотреть в википедии [Список кодов состояния HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP)

Answer (score 2):

Указать, что надо сформировать какой-то другой код HTTP-ответа вместо дефолтного 200 можно с помощью функции [`http_response_code`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php).

```
http_response_code(404);
```

А так же можно по старинке прямым формированием отдаваемых заголовков через вызов `header`. Например,

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```